# Cannot assign lpCmdLine parameter to a char* pointer

Tags: c++, mfc, lptstr

This code check run application this param:

```
INT APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, INT iShow)
{

    char* szCmdLine = lpCmdLine;

...
}
```

> Error this lines : error C2440: 'initializing' cannot convert from 'LPTSTR' to 'char *'

Comment: Does `TCHAR* szCmdLine = lpCmdLine;` work? Afaik an LPTSTR consists of TCHAR, not char.

Answer (score 2):

Its because `LPTSTR` could be `LPSTR` or `LPWSTR` considening project UNICODE settings. When unicode is enabled application use `LPWSTR`, if not `LPSTR`.

`LPSTR` is just an alias for `char*`. `LPWSTR` - `wchar_t*`. `T` in `LPTSTR` mean `TCHAR` type which defenition can be `char` or `wchar_t` whatever `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` symbol is defined in your project.

`LP` means "long pointer", long is 32 bit memory address. `STR` - string.

So lets describe `LPSTR` - "long pointer to ANSI string"; `LPWSTR` - "long pointer to wide character string" and `LPTSTR` - "long pointer to `TCHAR` string".

To `W` or `T` letter can be added prefix `C` like `LPCSTR`, `LPCTSTR`, `LPCWSTR` wich means that these pointers are constant like `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`.

So your code must look like:

```
INT APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, INT iShow)
{

    TCHAR* szCmdLine = lpCmdLine;

...
}
```

or

```
INT APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, INT iShow)
{

    LPTSTR szCmdLine = lpCmdLine;

...
}
```